# About perl "use" keyword

Tags: perl, perl-module

I now have a perl file test.pl which have to reference other perl module Hello.pm, Hello.pm and test.pl was in the same directory ,and the package name declaration 
of Hello.pm is `package MRS::scripts::Hello`. So, how should I use module Hello.pm in test.pl?

I tried `use Hello` and `use MRS::scripts::Hello`, but system cannot find Hello.pm in @INC.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`use` takes a package name. It then changes each `::` to a path separator like `/` and appends `.pm`. Therefore, the correct usage is `use Hello;`.

There is one problem here: `Hello.pm` must be under one of the roots in `@INC`. On one of my perls, `@INC` has entries like

```
/home/amon/.config/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.1/lib/site_perl/5.18.1/i686-linux-thread-multi-64int
/home/amon/.config/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.1/lib/site_perl/5.18.1
/home/amon/.config/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.1/lib/5.18.1/i686-linux-thread-multi-64int
/home/amon/.config/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.1/lib/5.18.1
.
```

That last one is interesting: `.` stands for the current working directory. Unfortunately, this does not always match the location of the script. We can solve that with the `FindBin` module:

```
use FindBin;             # get the script location, populates $FindBin::Bin
use lib $FindBin::Bin;   # tell perl to look for modules next to your script
use MRS::scripts::Hello; # load your module
```

… assuming that the module is in the file `$FindBin::Bin/MRS/scripts/Hello.pm`.

Comment: For `use` to successfully import any symbols exported by the module, the `use` must match the `package` in the file, so `use Hello` is not correct. The file needs to be placed at `MRS/scripts/Hello.pm` under an `@INC` directory, then `use MRS::scripts::Hello`.

Answer (score 2):

If the package name is `MRS::scripts::Hello`, perl searches for `MRS/scripts/Hello.pm`. Either create the directory structure, or remove the namespaces from the module file.

In other words, there are *three* things that must be in accord: file path, package name, and the argument to `use`.

If you want to change the package name, be careful. If there are any mentions of the namespace (fully qualified names) in the script, you should change them too.

Comment: Also be sure to add the desired path to @INC if it is not there already.