# Why I cannot call a module's function after required or used successfully?

Tags: perl, require, perl-module, subroutine

I have a Perl module file named `genbank.pm`, it has a subroutine `new`; this Perl module didn't use `Exporter` and didn't define `@EXPORT` or `@EXPORT_OK`. In the same directory I have a Perl file named `test.pl`, the code of `test.pl` is:

```
require 'genbank.pm';
use strict;
our $result = genbank::new();
```

When I run it with Komodo , it reports:

```
Undefined subroutine &genbank::new called at /home/mrs/scripts/test.pl line 3;
```

After I changed the code from

```
our $result = genbank::new();
```

to

```
our $result = genbank->new();
```

it said:

`Can't locate object method "new" via package "genbank"(perhaps you forgot to load "genbank"?) at /home/mrs/scripts/test.pl line 3.`

Comment: What happens when you `use genbank;` instead of `require ...`? Inside `genbank.pm`, is there a `package genbank;` declaration near the top?

Comment: No ,the package declaration in genbank.pm is   "package MRS::Scripts::genbank",it's the only package declaration in file genbank.pm . .So,what's the next step?

Comment: It makes no difference to change from "require ..." to "use ...".

Comment: After I change the package declaration from "package MRS::Scripts::genbank" to a simple "package genbank",the call works.So ,my question is ,what can I do to make the call successful and on the other hand keep the package declaration as "package MRS::Scripts::genbank"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [About perl "use" keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527726/about-perl-use-keyword)

Answer (score 3):

You haven't provided enough information to be entirely certain of the problem, but the most likely cause is that the `new` sub is in a package other than `genbank`.

When you attempt to call `genbank::new` (or `genbank->new`), Perl looks for a sub named `new` in the package `genbank`, *not* in the file `genbank.pm`.  By convention, the file `genbank.pm` will contain a package named `genbank`, but this is purely a matter of convention and convenience.  It is **not** enforced by the language and there is **absolutely no** automatic connection between file names and package names.

To find out what package your subs are being placed in, look in `genbank.pm` for any lines saying `package xxxx;`.  The last one to appear before the `sub new` line will tell you the package that `new` belongs to.  If there isn't a `package` statement before its definition, it will be in the package `main` by default.

(If you are responsible for the `genbank.pm` source code, I would also suggest either adding `package genbank;` to the file or renaming the file to match the package it actually contains, so as to avoid this sort of confusion in the future.)

**Edit in response to OP's comment:**

Since the module currently starts with `package MRS::Scripts::genbank`, then that's the package the `new` sub is created in.  You have two options for calling it:

1. Call it as `MRS::Scripts::genbank::new` (or, if it actually is an object constructor, `MRS::Scripts::genbank->new`).  If you want to call it using a package name, then you have to use the correct package name.
2. Export it from the `MRS::Scripts::genbank` package and modify your calling script to import symbols from that package (either by moving `genbank.pm` to `MRS/Scripts/genbank.pm` and changing your `require` to `use MRS::Scripts::genbank;` *or* by adding `MRS::Scripts::genbank->import;` after the `require`), then call it as just `new()`.  While this would work within the limited scope of your question, I advise **strongly** against it because, as soon as you repeat this with another module containing a `sub new`, it will all fall apart, since there can't be two `new`s at the same time in the same place.

The cleanest way to resolve this would be to move `genbank.pm` to `MRS/Scripts/genbank.pm`, change your `require` to `require MRS::Scripts::genbank.pm` (or `use`; if you don't export anything, they're equivalent), and then call the sub as `MRS::Scripts::genbank::new` or `MRS::Scripts::genbank->new`.  This approach will bring the file name and package name into sync with each other, which will make life easier for whoever has to maintain the code in the future (which will probably be you...).

Comment: Yes , the package declaration is "package MRS::Scripts::genbank".This declaration lies in the first line of file genbank.pm and it's the only package declaration .So ,what should I do next?

Comment: After I change the package declaration from "package MRS::Scripts::genbank" to a simple "package genbank",the call works.So ,my question is ,what can I do to make the call successful and on the other hand keep the package declaration as "package MRS::Scripts::genbank"?

Comment: @Vico_Wu I've edited my answer to explain how to make this work, given the additional information in your comment.

Comment: `require MRS::Scripts::genbank` or `require 'MRS/Scripts/genbank.pm'`